# java - capture mouse event from standalone java app

Tags: java

I want to capture Mouse Event outside the standalone java application. Can anybody point me where to get some sample?

I have found examples showing how to capture mouse events inside JFrame or JPanel. I would like to capture any mouse or keyboard event after the standalone java application starts.

Thanks.

Comment: In a word, don't do this as Java is not the language for trying to fiddle with things close to the OS. Use C or a utility language (such as AutoIt if in Windows).

Comment: *"I would like to capture any mouse or keyboard event"*  Doesn't the world have enough spyware/malware already?

Answer (score 0):

You will only recieve mouse and keyboard events when your application is in focus, and for the appropriate component. You will have to use a platform specific API for retrieving all mouse and keyboard events (read, JNI).